# Adding Panel to Panel

Tags: java, swing

I anted to add a JPanel to my already existing JPanel so I could have a small window with a JTextField on top with a name and a scrollable JTextArea below it with some description. I made a class that extends JPanel with the following constructor:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class LocationWindow extends JPanel {
    public JTextField name;
    public JTextArea desc;
    public JScrollPane scroll;

    public LocationWindow(){
        super();
        setBorder (new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Display Area"));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(30, 40, 700, 290);
        name = new JTextField(10);
        name.setText("name");
        desc = new JTextArea(5,10);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(desc);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        desc.setEditable (true);
        desc.setLineWrap(true);
        desc.setText("random text");
        add(name);
        add(desc);
        add(scroll);
        validate();
    }
}
```

It almost works, as it gives me the window with the borders and a scroll, but both the JTextField and JTextArea are missing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). `setBounds(30, 40, 700, 290);`  Don't do that.  Use layout padding and borders for white space in a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for the JPanel,

```
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

the components will always be added to the center if you dont specify the position.  `add(scroll);` is same as  `add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);` as you're adding all via add the last added component only be visible.Refer [this as well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)

The next is you are adding JTextArea seperately so it will be removed from ScrollPane.Just add scrollpane to Panel no need to add all components.[Add the parent component alone]

```
    add(name,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //add(desc);Noo need to add desc as it is already added in JScrollPane
    add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

There is no need for setVisible for JPanel.JPanel needs to be embedded in Container like JFrame to be visible

```
         //setVisible(true);Wont do anything
```

So call like this

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new LocationWindow());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You! This is very usefull, I did not know those detail since my other panel doesn't have a layout.

Comment: Unless you specifically set the layout of your other panel to null, it *does* have a layout - the default layout for a JPanel, which is FlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to adding panel to panel.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    LocationWindow loc = new LocationWindow();
    frame.add(loc);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Problem is I can't access my frame after it has already been created when I need to add that panel. So everything that happens happens in another panel to which I want to add this one.